# How to accept 'theirs-conflict' to resolve tree conflict: Local add, incoming add upon merge

Tags: svn, merge, tree-conflict

I have come across the following basic Tree conflict: Local add, incoming add upon merge.

I know we can use `svn resolve --accept working file` to resolve it, but SVN prevent me to use  `accept their-conflict` to accept the incoming version.

Can anyone tell me how to replace my local file by the incoming one? Is it possible using `svn resolved file` in any way?

Comment: One option is to move your local file out of the way, do an `svn update`, put your file back, and then do an `svn commit`.  Granted it's probably not the "correct" way to do it, but it's probably a lot simpler than playing with the SVN commands.

Comment: @aroth, these files are already existed both in trunk and branch (background: I merge the branch to trunk weekly), in fact, I want to use the one in branch to overwrite the one in trunk, as you said, I need to delete these files in trunk, then commit, then merge them from branch, right?

Comment: @malenkiy_scot,No,for some history reasons,I didn't verify whether the steps which I indicated are right or not. The tree conflicts are caused by repeating merge, so I deleted the svn:mergeinfo property of the sub directory, let it inherit it's parent one(the correct one), it works in my situation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The right thing to do is detect this problem in a previous --dry-run and delete the local conflicting dir with `svn delete` before doing the merge.

First scenario: Working copy with the merge already done.
Solution: Delete the working copy, checkout a clean copy and do the right thing.

Second scenario: Already commited wrong directory, after `svn resolve --accept=working`.

You must `svn delete` the conflicting directory, and rerun the merge from the parent directory of the conflicting directory ignoring `mergeinfo`. Revert every object except the previous conflicting directory (now there isn't conflict). Check and commit the changes.

Ex. Working copy un WC folder. Your conflict in A/conflictDir directory:

```
cd A
svn delete conflictDir
svn merge --ignore-ancestry -rbeginRev:endRev <URLrepo/A>
svn -R revert `ls | grep -v conflictDir`
<... check ...>
svn ci -m "conflictDir fixed"
```

Answer (score 10):

I had similar problem, where I svn update a file which has conflict with my local file. I want the remote copy to replace my local copy. What I did is 
    `svn delete file_name`, 
and then 
    `svn revert file_name`. 
It recovers to the remote copy. I am not sure if the first svn delete is necessary or not.

Comment: It was for me, deleting the file just with `rm` caused the conflict to remain, but deleting it with `svn delete` and then restored it fixed the tree conflict.

Comment: These conflicts also occur on incoming delete. Then `svn revert DIR` will delete the directory and the conflict is gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tree conflict on 'wp-content/plugins/cm-alpha/condensed-back.js'
> local file replace, incoming file edit upon update
Select: (mc) keep affected local moves,
    (r) mark resolved (breaks moves), (p) postpone,
    (q) quit resolution, (h) help:
```

After I replied with r

```
Resolved conflicted state of 'wp-content/plugins/cm-alpha/condensed-back.js'
Summary of conflicts:
Tree conflicts: 0 remaining (and 1 already resolved)
```

... and it continued on with update

```
Updating 'wp-content/plugins':
A    wp-content/plugins/cm-jobs/both-ends/php/ajax-prc
U    wp-content/plugins/cm-eats/condensed-front.css
U    wp-content/plugins/cm-eats/condensed-front.min.css
U    wp-content/plugins/cm-estore/condensed-front.css
Updated to revision 304.
At revision 304.
```

Upon completion I did a 'before' look at the file in question with

```
ls wp-content/plugins/cm-alpha/condensed-back.js -l
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 793528 Oct 19 21:13 condensed-back.js
```

I then ran these 2 commands:

```
sudo svn delete condensed-back.js --force
sudo svn revert condensed-back.js
```

I then did a 'after' look at the file in question which confirmed it was in fact updated to the latest repo version

```
ls wp-content/plugins/cm-alpha/condensed-back.js -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 794427 Oct 25 22:08 condensed-back.js
```

As you can see the bytesize is different and the date is the most recent date.  So this procedure worked as mentioned elsewhere in this post.  I just wanted to show it procedurally to take any grey area out of the process.